# Where can I add own entitlements in XCODE 13?

Tags: xcode13

As Apple changes its xcode every year, where in xcode 13 I can add own entitlements?

This site ist two years old and apple changed the position.
https://medium.com/macoclock/everything-you-need-to-do-to-launch-an-applescript-from-appkit-on-macos-catalina-with-swift-1ba82537f7c3

I know, there's .entitlements, but xcode doesn't like it at all change this file manually.
So where do I find the ability to add my own app-ids / entitlements like "com.moneymoney-app.retail" or "com.apple.iWork.Pages" to grant access for my apple script?

Short screenshot eagerly desired. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. If you found the solution yourself you should post the answer as an answer and accept it, so that the question is not left open.